# $_GET form variables in a loop

Tags: php

I've got a form with input names like `price1`, `price2`, `price3` and I'm trying to get these values in another page. I'm sending it using `GET`.

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $qtd_itens; $i++) {
  $price = $_GET['price" + $i + "'];
  echo $price;
}
```

How should I declare the `$price` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to put . in place of + sign...

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $qtd_itens; $i++) {
      $price = $_GET['price'. $i. ''];
      echo $price;
    }
```

Comment: could be reduced to `"price$i"`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to collect all the prices you can do:

```
$prices = array();
for ($i = 1; $i < $qtd_itens; $i++) {
  $prices[] = $_GET["price" . $i];
}
var_dump($prices);
```

To clarify:

```
$arr[] = "a";
```

is shorthand for:

```
array_push($arr, "a");
```

or

```
$arr[$i] = "a";
```

Comment: I'd also use isset() on the _GET instead of assuming it exists.

Comment: There is `$qtd_itens` so I'm not complaining. @GilbertoGonçalvesMachado that seems to be syntax error use `$_GET["price" . $i]`. Unlike other languages PHP uses `.` to concatenate strings, so `"a" . "b"` instead of `"a" + "b"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you form input having price1, price2, price3... etc, you simply make this for view content of data send:

```
print_r($_REQUEST)
```

This show you data in array send, and collect with foreach with this:

```
$prices = array();
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key=>$val) {
  $prices[$key] = $val;
}
print_r($prices);
```